# Rebuild / reinstall all R libraries - match current R version

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to reinstall / rebuild all my libraries in **R** so that they match my current R version (3.5.1).

I'm aware of multiple posts on this board and the default answer to run:
`update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE)`
but for reasons I don't understand running this command still fails to update all the libs.

For example, after trying to update libraries via GUI, via CLI or even manually I still see that some of the packages where built for 3.5.0:

```
> devtools::session_info()
Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.456)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Polish_Poland.1250          
 tz       Europe/Warsaw               
 date     2018-09-15                  

Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package        * version     date       source                             
 abind            1.4-5       2016-07-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 assertthat       0.2.0       2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 backports        1.1.2       2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 base           * 3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 base64enc        0.1-3       2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 bayesplot        1.6.0       2018-08-02 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 bindr            0.1.1       2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 bindrcpp         0.2.2       2018-03-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 bridgesampling   0.5-2       2018-08-19 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 brms           * 2.5.0       2018-09-13 Github (paul-buerkner/brms@4e0a9cd)
 Brobdingnag      1.2-6       2018-08-13 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 coda             0.19-1      2016-12-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 colorspace       1.3-2       2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 colourpicker     1.0         2017-09-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 compiler         3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 crayon           1.3.4       2017-09-16 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 crosstalk        1.0.0       2016-12-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 datasets       * 3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 devtools         1.13.6      2018-06-27 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 digest           0.6.16      2018-08-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 dplyr            0.7.6       2018-06-29 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 DT               0.4         2018-01-30 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 dygraphs         1.1.1.6     2018-07-11 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 ggplot2        * 3.0.0       2018-07-03 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 ggridges         0.5.0       2018-04-05 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 glue             1.3.0       2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 graphics       * 3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 grDevices      * 3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 grid             3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 gridExtra        2.3         2017-09-09 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 gtable           0.2.0       2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 gtools           3.8.1       2018-06-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 htmltools        0.3.6       2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 htmlwidgets      1.2         2018-04-19 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 httpuv           1.4.5       2018-07-19 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 igraph           1.2.2       2018-07-27 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 inline           0.3.15      2018-05-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 installr         0.21.0      2018-08-22 Github (talgalili/installr@c4e356b)
 later            0.7.4       2018-08-31 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 lattice          0.20-35     2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 lazyeval         0.2.1       2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 lme4           * 1.1-18.9000 2018-09-13 Github (lme4/lme4@5303c28)         
 loo              2.0.0       2018-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 magrittr         1.5         2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 markdown         0.8         2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 MASS             7.3-50      2018-04-30 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 Matrix         * 1.2-14      2018-04-13 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 matrixStats      0.54.0      2018-07-23 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 memoise          1.1.0       2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 methods        * 3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 mime             0.5         2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 miniUI           0.1.1.1     2018-05-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 minqa            1.2.4       2014-10-09 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 munsell          0.5.0       2018-06-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 mvtnorm          1.0-8       2018-05-31 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 nlme             3.1-137     2018-04-07 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 nloptr           1.0.4       2017-08-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 parallel         3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 pillar           1.3.0.9000  2018-09-13 Github (r-lib/pillar@3fabb4e)      
 pkgconfig        2.0.2       2018-08-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 plyr             1.8.4       2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 promises         1.0.1       2018-04-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 purrr            0.2.5       2018-05-29 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 R6               2.2.2       2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 Rcpp           * 0.12.18     2018-07-23 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 reshape2         1.4.3       2017-12-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 RevoUtils      * 11.0.1      2018-08-01 local                              
 RevoUtilsMath  * 11.0.0      2018-08-01 local                              
 rlang            0.2.2       2018-08-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 rsconnect        0.8.8       2018-03-09 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 rstan            2.17.3      2018-01-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 rstantools       1.5.1       2018-08-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 rstudioapi       0.7         2017-09-07 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 scales           1.0.0       2018-08-09 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 shiny            1.1.0       2018-05-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 shinyjs          1.0         2018-01-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 shinystan        2.5.0       2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 shinythemes      1.1.1       2016-10-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 splines          3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 StanHeaders      2.17.2      2018-01-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 stats          * 3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 stats4           3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 stringi          1.2.4       2018-07-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 stringr          1.3.1       2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 threejs          0.3.1       2017-08-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 tibble           1.4.99.9004 2018-09-13 Github (hadley/tibble@e54aeeb)     
 tidyselect       0.2.4       2018-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0)                     
 tools            3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 utils          * 3.5.1       2018-08-05 local                              
 withr            2.1.2       2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 xtable           1.8-3       2018-08-29 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 xts              0.11-0      2018-07-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 yaml             2.2.0       2018-07-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1)                     
 zoo              1.8-3       2018-07-16 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```

Is it because there is no other version or It's something I could fix at my end?